# React: react-datepicker won't update state

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am trying to do on change on datepicker, but the state doesn't update. I am using a state from props. So the date already exists. It shows expired dates. When I am doing the on change, it get stuck at the current date.

Something I am missing in the onChange handler?

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {export} = this.props;
    this.state = {showCalender: false};
    this.date = export.expires;

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.export.expires !== state.expires) {
      return {
        expires: props.export.expires
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      expires: date
    }, console.log(this.state.expires));
    this.handleClick();
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({showCalender: !this.state.showCalender});
  }

  handleClear() {
    this.setState({expires: ''});
  }

  render() {
    const {expires, showCalender} = this.state;
    const expiresDate = format(expires, 'MM/dd/yyyy');

    return (
        <div>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormControl
              id="date"
              value={expiresDate}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
              title="set date"
              aria-label="set date"
            />
            <Button className="close-btn" onClick={() => this.handleClear()}>Clear</Button>
          </FormGroup>
          { showCalender && (
            <FormGroup>
              <DatePicker
                selected={expires}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                inline
              />
            </FormGroup>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: `export` is a reserved keyword in ES6 so I highly encourage to change the name of the variable. If you are compiling this using ES6 it should throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update the state you are triggering a re-render, but just before the next render, react is calling the `getDerivedStateFromProps` which there you are checking to see if the values are different:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.export.expires !== state.expires) {
      return {
        expires: props.export.expires
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Which they are, as you just updated the `state` but the `props` stayed the same. 
And then you update the state again but now you set it back to whatever the value in props is.

From the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?#static-getderivedstatefromprops):

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates.

I'm not sure why you are trying to sync props and state, but usually this indicates a bad design of your app.

As mentioned in the comments, do not use a variable named `export` as its a reserved word since ES2015.

You might get an error of:

> Unexpected keyword 'export'

Comment: Ahh! I changed it completely different and removed this, and now it works. Thank you!!